# Managing Nginx FastCGI cache files

Tags: nginx

I just recently deleted millions of cache files, about 150GB worth from my server.  It took hours and a lot of resources to do it.  I never scrubbed them before because I assumed invalidated cache files were being removed.  Does Nginx remove these files automatically or should I periodically run a script to remove them myself?

Answer (score 0):

From reading http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_cache_path I would note that cache size and contents are managed through following options to `fastcgi_cache_path` directive:

- `inactive`: "*Cached data that are not accessed during the time specified by the inactive parameter get removed from the cache regardless of their freshness. By default, inactive is set to 10 minutes.*" So I would suppose that with default settings all files that were not accessed within last 10 minutes should be removed;
- `max_size`: "*The special cache manager process monitors the maximum cache size set by the* `max_size` *parameter. When this size is exceeded, it removes the least recently used data.*".

I would guess that you do not have `max_size` limit set at all. So with large number of objects with large expiration times you could end up with a pretty big cache.